# What package is dirname located in for freebsd

Tags: freebsd, pfsense

I am trying to install some software on pfsense 1.2.3 but the scripts are complaining about not finding the dirname binary. I have done a find on the system but cannot find it, and google is not helping either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably pieces (maybe more than just dirname) of stock FreeBSD that we don't include in pfSense as they aren't needed for firewall or related purposes. You can just copy over from a stock 7.2 release for 1.2.3.

Answer (score 0):

I'd have thought it was part of the base system.  Have you tried just typing dirname or which dirname, and see what comes back?  Your scripts might be clearing $PATH and not include /bin or /usr/bin as part of the definition, causing this kind of error.

Comment: Yeah thats what I expected :( I tried doing a find / -name dirname ... its not there, so I am downloading freebsd 7.2 and will try to extract binary from there.

Comment: It is part of the base install, but as Chris Buechler points out, not all of base is included in pfSense.